# Only leave n elements in slice

Tags: go, slice

Please see [this playground](https://play.golang.org/p/qm5RrI0iBe). As you can see I have a slice within a struct. I also have a method which can be used to add a new element to the slice. This works fine.

But now my problem is that I want to extend the method so that it leaves `n` elements of the slice. So when adding a new element, the "oldest" should be removed and the new one should be added.

How can I do this? Aren't there out-of-the-box packages which I can use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For example,

`addimport.go`:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

type Statistics struct {
    LastScan time.Time
    Imports  []Import
}

type Import struct {
    text string
}

func (s *Statistics) AddImport(i Import) {
    // only the last n entries are kept
    const n = 2 // n > 0 and small
    if len(s.Imports) >= n {
        copy(s.Imports, s.Imports[len(s.Imports)-n+1:])
        s.Imports = s.Imports[:n-1]
    }
    s.Imports = append(s.Imports, i)
}

func main() {
    s := Statistics{}
    fmt.Println(len(s.Imports), cap(s.Imports), s.Imports)
    s.AddImport(Import{text: "myText1"})
    s.AddImport(Import{text: "myText2"})
    s.AddImport(Import{text: "myText3"})
    fmt.Println(len(s.Imports), cap(s.Imports), s.Imports)
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/204-uB8Zls

Output:

```
0 0 []
2 2 [{myText2} {myText3}]
```

---

Code should be reasonably efficient. Go has a benchmark package. Here are the benchmark results for the solutions from peterSO, Kaedys, and gonutz.

```
$ go test -bench=. addimport_test.go
BenchmarkAddImport/PeterSO-4   100000   16145 ns/op      96 B/op     3 allocs/op
BenchmarkAddImport/Kaedys-4     30000   59344 ns/op   32032 B/op   502 allocs/op
BenchmarkAddImport/Gonutz-4     30000   60447 ns/op   32032 B/op   502 allocs/op
```

`addimport_test.go`:

```
package main

import (
    "testing"
    "time"
)

type Statistics struct {
    LastScan time.Time
    Imports  []Import
}

type Import struct {
    text string
}

func (s *Statistics) AddImportPeterSO(i Import) {
    // only the last n entries are kept
    const n = 2 // n > 0 and small
    if len(s.Imports) >= n {
        copy(s.Imports, s.Imports[len(s.Imports)-n+1:])
        s.Imports = s.Imports[:n-1]
    }
    s.Imports = append(s.Imports, i)
}

const numberToKeep = 2

func (s *Statistics) AddImportKaedys(i Import) {
    s.Imports = append(s.Imports, i)
    if len(s.Imports) > numberToKeep {
        s.Imports = s.Imports[len(s.Imports)-numberToKeep:]
    }
}

func (s *Statistics) AddImportGonutz(i Import) {
    s.Imports = append(s.Imports, i)
    const max = 2
    if len(s.Imports) > max {
        s.Imports = s.Imports[1:]
    }
}

func benchmarkAddImport(b *testing.B, addImport func(*Statistics, Import)) {
    b.ReportAllocs()
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        var s Statistics
        for j := 0; j < 1000; j++ {
            addImport(&s, Import{})
        }
    }
}

func BenchmarkAddImport(b *testing.B) {
    b.Run("PeterSO", func(b *testing.B) {
        benchmarkAddImport(b, (*Statistics).AddImportPeterSO)
    })
    b.Run("Kaedys", func(b *testing.B) {
        benchmarkAddImport(b, (*Statistics).AddImportKaedys)
    })
    b.Run("Gonutz", func(b *testing.B) {
        benchmarkAddImport(b, (*Statistics).AddImportGonutz)
    })
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/Q2X_T5Vofe

---

The general form of this problem is a circular buffer: [Circular buffer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer).

Answer (score 3):

If you want to remove the first element (the one that has been in there the longest) from a slice `s`, you can simply do `s = s[1:]` which makes s a reference to the slice starting at the first element of the old slice.

I have modified your code to do this:

https://play.golang.org/p/Eu-KLoinz0

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

type Statistics struct {
    LastScan time.Time
    Imports  []Import
}

type Import struct {
    text string
}

func (s *Statistics) AddImport(i Import) {
    s.Imports = append(s.Imports, i)
    const max = 2
    if len(s.Imports) > max {
        s.Imports = s.Imports[len(s.Imports)-max:]
    }
}

func main() {
    s := Statistics{}
    s.AddImport(Import{text: "myText1"})
    fmt.Println(s.Imports)
    s.AddImport(Import{text: "myText2"})
    fmt.Println(s.Imports)
    s.AddImport(Import{text: "myText3"})
    fmt.Println(s.Imports)
    s.AddImport(Import{text: "myText4"})
    fmt.Println(s.Imports)
}
```

Comment: BUG: `s.Imports = s.Imports[1:]` is a bug. if `s.Imports` has more than `max` entries then you leave more than `max` entries in the slice:  https://play.golang.org/p/tRWk2cVfe0. `s.Imports[1:]` should be `s.Imports[len(s.Imports)-max:]`.

Comment: Realistically, if you're only ever adding entries via AddImport, you can never have more than `max+1` in it (after insert), because you're always removing an entry any time you add one to it.  Still, I tend to agree, as a just-in-case measure, as my answer reflects.

Answer (score 2):

Subslice.  The syntax `slice[n:m]` returns the portion of the input slice from n to m-1.  Either one can be omitted to imply 0 or len(slice), respectively.  So `slice[n:]` means "give me the portion of the slice from `n` to the end.  `slice[len(slice)-n:]` will give you the last `n` entries in the slice.

https://play.golang.org/p/4JRcRH-wc3

```
func (s *Statistics) AddImport(i Import) {
    // How can I optimize this method so that
    // only the last two entries are kept?

    s.Imports = append(s.Imports, i)
    if len(s.Imports) > numberToKeep {
        s.Imports = s.Imports[len(s.Imports)-numberToKeep:]
    }
}
```

Note that this does not remove the start of the slice from memory (or allow it to be garbage collected), but as you continue to add entries, the runtime will automatically allocate larger underlying arrays and copy the contents, freeing earlier array allocations to be garbage collected.  It currently does this on a factor-of-2 basis (so it does it every time the slice doubles in size), though this is not documented and thus not guaranteed to remain this way.  If memory management is important to you, you can manually copy the slice to a new backing array using the built-in `copy(dest, source)` function.

Advanced options include using a queue system (which are typically implemented using a linked list format) or a circular slice (where entries "wrap" around from the end to unused indexes at the start of the array, another common queue design).